# New Android 13 Photo Picker EXIF location not working

Tags: android, photo, exif, android-13, photo-picker

I am just implementing the new Android 13 photo picker and I simply cannot get the EXIF location of the selected photos.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_PICK_IMAGES_MAX, 5);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_NEW_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

... getting the photos and checking for EXIF location:

```
for (int i = 0; i < returnedIntent.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
    Uri uri = returnedIntent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

    InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(input);

    // Works! 
    String dateTime = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);

    // NULL
    String latDest = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LATITUDE);

    // Not set
    String lat = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);

    // NULL
    double[] latLng = exifInterface.getLatLong();
}
```

I requested the `android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` and the `android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, they are both granted, but it still does not work!

Any ideas?

Tobias

### UPDATE

It seems Google doesn't allow it on purpose !
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243294058

Comment: You also need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: This permission is too much, has to works without! But I just read somewhere, that Google currently doesn’t allow it?

Comment: You should just test if it works with that as then you know. Something diferent is publishing in play store.

Comment: The permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not an option. It has to work without.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243294058

Comment: It is a pitty that you did not post here an example of such a content scheme. It would have made the problem immediately clear as its that special provider that strips the gps information at serving the file. Please do add it yet at start of your post.

Comment: From your issue: `We will consider the location info as a feature request.` My god.. a feature! They intentionally removed the gps info. What feature!

Comment: Wow...what a surprise...! I can't believe that google made a feature without a feature...;;;